# My code keeps going back to the goto after every line when there is an error

Tags: excel, vba, onerror

I have the following code:

```
On Error GoTo no_match
found_discord = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(char, table_rng.ListColumns("Chars").DataBodyRange, 0)
discord = table_rng.DataBodyRange(found_discord, 8).Value

If discord = "" Then

    answer = MsgBox("This user has no discord on file. Do you know his discord?", vbYesNo)
    
    If answer = "yes" Then
        
        discord = InputBox("Please type user discord:")
    
        
        If (Me.OptForever.Value = True And discord = "") Then
        
            discord = "Banned Forever"
        
        End If
        
    Else
        
        If Me.OptForever.Value = True Then
        
            discord = "Banned Forever"
        
        Else
        
            discord = "No disc found"
        
        End If
    
    End If
    
End If

Set lrow = table_notes.ListRows.Add
    
With lrow
        
    .Range(1) = char
    .Range(2) = length
    .Range(3) = Date
    .Range(4) = end_time
    .Range(6) = reason
    .Range(7) = discord
            
End With

Check_discord discord, char, length, end_time, reason

sort_table4

lock_pass

Unload Me
Exit Sub

no_match:
    MsgBox ("This Char is new to our database please insert data after clicking ok")
    frmNewChar.Show
    found_discord = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(char, table_rng.ListColumns("Chars").DataBodyRange, 0)
    discord = table_rng.DataBodyRange(found_discord, 8).Value
    Resume Next
    
End Sub
```

The idea is for the code to use match function to lookup value. (this part works fine).

My issue is when the Match function doesn't find a match.
Instead of running the code in the "no_match" area once and then continue with the rest of the code,
VBA jumps to "no_match" after every line after the "if" statement.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following after the match function line

```vb
on error goto 0
```